# Idiomatic scala solution to combining sequences

Tags: scala, functional-programming, sequence, seq

Imagine a function `combineSequences: (seqs: Set[Seq[Int]])Set[Seq[Int]]` that combines sequences when the last item of first sequence matches the first item of the second sequence.  For example, if you have the following sequences:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(5, 6, 7, 8)
(8, 9, 10)
(3, 4, 10)
```

The result of `combineSequences` would be:

```
(5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10)
(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 10)
```

Because sequences 1, 2, and 5 combine together.  If multiple sequences could combine to create a different result, the decisions is arbitrary.  For example, if we have the sequences:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
```

There are two correct answers.  Either:

```
(1, 2, 2, 3)
(2, 4)
```

Or:

```
(1, 2, 2, 4)
(2, 3)
```

I can only think of a very imperative and fairly opaque implementation.  I'm wondering if anyone has a solution that would be more idiomatic scala.  I've run into related problems a few times now.

Comment: The first result should be (5,6,7,8,8,9,10) and (1,2,2,3,3,4,10) right?

Comment: xs.map(y => xs.foldLeft[Seq[Int]](y)((acc, b) => if(acc.last == b.head) acc ++ b; else acc))   Best I could come up with this late at night.. it leaves the originals in the set, so not a complete solution, but might put you on the right track

Comment: I also struggle with thinking functionally. I recently wrote a blog post that should help you: [Map, reduce, and fold for the programmatically imperative | prose :: and :: conz](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/09/09/map-reduce-and-fold-for-the-programmatically-imperative/)

Comment: You should use `SortedSet[Seq[Int]]` instead, since `Set` doesn't guarantee the sequences' order which you depend on.

Comment: @Chirlo That's not necessary for a solution, especially since he doesn't care which of the possible correct answers he gets.

Comment: @itsbruce, he doesn't care which of the possible correct answer he gets, but the answer still needs to be correct. If he has a `Set` that delivers the sequences from his example on this order : `(2,3), (2,4), (1,2)` then they wont' be combined

Comment: @Chirlo If the solution is correct, then *where there is only one possible solution*, the order of inputs can only make a difference to the *order* of the outputs (and it may not always do so - consider the case where all the inputs can be combined into a single sequence).  It is only where there is more than one possible outcome that the order of inputs  matter.  If you care about that, by all means sort the input, but it is *not necessary* to satisfy the spec.

Comment: To be clear, if `f(Set(SeqA, SeqB, SeqC))` has only one answer `Set(SeqD, SeqC)` then re-ordering the inputs *can only* change the order of `SeqD` and `SeqC`; it cannot give a different distinct set of Sequences.  But if there are two possible answers, `Set(SeqD, SeqC)` and `Set(SeqB, SeqE)`, then the order of the inputs *might* be significant, depending on the implementation.  But the OP explicitly said he doesn't care.

Comment: I chose a bad example that suggested some easier solutions.  I also shouldn't have used sequences of sorted numbers in my examples.

Comment: @schmmd Could you update ypur examples to show a better range of acceptable inputs snd outputs, with edge cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not the most optimized solution but I've gone for readability.

```
def combineSequences[T]( seqs: Set[Seq[T]] ): Set[Seq[T]] = {
  if ( seqs.isEmpty ) seqs
  else {
    val (seq1, otherSeqs) = (seqs.head, seqs.tail)
    otherSeqs.find(_.headOption == seq1.lastOption) match {
      case Some( seq2 ) => combineSequences( otherSeqs - seq2 + (seq1 ++ seq2) )
      case None =>
        otherSeqs.find(_.lastOption == seq1.headOption) match {
          case Some( seq2 ) => combineSequences( otherSeqs - seq2 + (seq2 ++ seq1) )
          case None => combineSequences( otherSeqs ) + seq1
        }
    }
  }
}
```

REPL test:

```
scala> val seqs = Set(Seq(1, 2), Seq(2, 3), Seq(5, 6, 7, 8), Seq(8, 9, 10), Seq(3, 4, 10))
seqs: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Seq[Int]] = Set(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(8, 9, 10), List(5, 6, 7, 8), List(3, 4, 10))
scala> combineSequences( seqs )
res10: Set[Seq[Int]] = Set(List(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 10), List(5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10))
scala> val seqs = Set(Seq(1, 2), Seq(2, 3, 100), Seq(5, 6, 7, 8), Seq(8, 9, 10), Seq(100, 4, 10))
seqs: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Seq[Int]] = Set(List(100, 4, 10), List(1, 2), List(8, 9, 10), List(2, 3, 100), List(5, 6, 7, 8))
scala> combineSequences( seqs )
res11: Set[Seq[Int]] = Set(List(5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10), List(1, 2, 2, 3, 100, 100, 4, 10))
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  Any ideas on readable solutions if you couldn't presort the list?  In making an analogous problem I made it too easy.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for all sequences I could have described, although it works for my examples.  What if you had `Seq(Seq(1, 2), Seq(2, 3, 100), Seq(5, 6, 7, 8), Seq(8, 9, 10), Seq(100, 4, 10)`?  You won't get a connection between the second seq and the last seq because they do not sort next to each other.

Comment: You're right, I guess I should have paid more attention to the requirements and less to the test set. I updated my answer, I do think it is correct now, and is still relatively easy to understand.